# Slick Slider not fits inside container

Tags: css, slick.js

I am using a slick slider inside a container.The container has two columns namely col-1 and col-2.
I want it to be side by side ,for that i have used flex but it doesn't work.Can anyone please help me to resolve this  issue.My aim is to achieve such a slider where the testimonial text section is fixed and only the right one scrolls.The problem is that when flex is used the testmonial slider boxes get down  as aseperate row
[image]

```js
$(".testimonial-slider-wrap").slick({
    dots: true,
    arrows: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    variableWidth: true,
    speed: 300,
  })
```

```css
.testimonial-main-wrap {
     max-width: 136rem;
     margin-left: auto;
}
 .testimonial-main-wrap {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
}
 .testimonial-col-1 {
     max-width: 39.5rem;
     margin-right: 4.2rem;
}
```

```html
<section id="testimonial">
    <div class="testimonial-main-wrap">
        <div class="testimonial-col-1">
          <p>What Zaiyna clients say</p>
        </div>
        <div class="testimonial-col-2">
            <div class="testimonial-slider-wrap">
              <div class="testimonial-slides">
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you want to archieve, but try putting `width:50%` to both `col-1` and `col-2`. This way the two elements can be sharing same row in the screen.

Comment: thanks for the help.I want the colums to be placed side by side.Since the second column contains slick slider it strecthes out of the container.That's what i am facing now

Comment: You can try and play with the z-index of the elements, so they can't be seen when they invade the other element's space.